# Terminal stays on top even after I click on a notification of another app

Tags: macos, terminal, mouse, focus

I have a couple of issues with the macOS Terminal app.

1. I'm working on the Terminal and I get a Slack notification. I click on the notification to jump to the Slack message — and Slack takes me there — but Terminal stays on top. I can see Slack behind the Terminal because I've transparency settings on.
2. I use Mac Mouse  Fix app to hide apps with a single click of a mouse button. It works on all apps [except the Terminal](https://github.com/noah-nuebling/mac-mouse-fix/discussions/492).

I feel somehow these are connected, but I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer to my own question. For anyone facing the same issue, it's because of "Secure Keyboard Entry" option on the Terminal app. This is checked by default after Big Sur (from Monterey, I think). On my work computer, this is controlled by Enterprise IT so I'm unable to uncheck it.

**Solution**: I started using iTerm2.

https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/terminal/trml109/mac